# dynamic update does not fire ng-change of textfield

Tags: angularjs

I am facing one problem with textbox in angularjs.
When I am updating textfield data by some way(Like clicking button) then ng-change is not working. Please check plnkr

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/32eE0ejSNBTkWJ4LVErR?p=preview][1]
```

When I am updating first name on button click ng-change is not firing, but when i am changing first name in textfield ng-change is getting fired

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is intended. It says this in the official documentation:

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input
>   value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> It will not be evaluated:
>
> - if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has
>     not changed
> - if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null
> - if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value

[source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

In your case, the last item in that list applies.

> if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value

You'll have to use a watch in this case.